# Pip will not let me uninstall typing module

Tags: python, pip, module

I run a Unix server that uses environment modules to handle different software packages. While installing JCVI I have been running into multiple errors. The most recent error I have gotten was this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

After doing some googling, I found a solution that told me to uninstall the typing module as there are problems with that module from python 3.7 and above (this server runs 3.8).

I attempted to uninstall this module, but it outputs the exact same error :

```
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

that I had before. I do not know how to go about either removing typing or fixing the error another way.

Comment: Why are you trying to uninstall the `typing` module? It is built into python and is not meant to be uninstalled.

Comment: reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833509/attributeerror-type-object-callable-has-no-attribute-abc-registry

Comment: Downgrading packages, especially after the next version comes out, is almost always a wrong and obsolete answer.  It may be briefly right until the bugs are fixed.

Comment: You may be running an old version of pip.  Try python -m pip install...   or upgrade pip.